# Phone Number Formating using Formula field

Tags: formula-field, phone

I'm getting Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' on the following formula basically want to remove spaces and + in the beginning

I want to format the phone as per below examples

0469 407 546 to 61469407546 or
+61469 407 546 to 61469407546

```
IF(BEGINS(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MobilePhone, " ", ""), "+", ""), "0"),  
TRIM(right(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MobilePhone, " ", ""), "+", ""), 
LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MobilePhone, " ", ""), "+", "") - 1))),  
IF(NOT(BEGINS(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MobilePhone, " ", ""), "+", "")), "61"), 
"61"+SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MobilePhone, " ", ""), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MobilePhone, " ", ""), "+", ""))))
```

appreciate if you could help in the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
IF( LEFT(Phone, 1) = "+", 
    RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(Phone , " ", ""), 11),
    IF(LEFT(Phone, 1) = "0",
       "61" & RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(Phone , " ", ""), 9),
       SUBSTITUTE(Phone , " ", "")
    )
)
```

In this formula first, check if the first character is "+" or not if "+" then remove space from the phone and then get 11 characters from the phone. same way in the second condition first check whether the first character is "0" or not. if "0" is found then remove the space from the phone and get 9 characters from the phone and append the "61" into the phone.

Refer to the screenshot of output for the reference.
[image]
[image]